# Acessing DLLs in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, api, dll

I'm not that good with VB.NET yet and I'd like to learn about API's and external DLL files.

Perhaps someone can post some sample code with explanation/comments or point me to some tutorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/PInvoke.aspx

Comment: Thank you. Plus one for now. I would like to keep this question open for a while so I can get more links.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of DLLs?  For native DLLs, you have to [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx) (assuming the entry is public and non-decorated).  For managed, just add a reference and use it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. Actually, I *dont* understand it. What does *non-decorated* mean? Also, what is *Managed*?

Comment: If you don't know what "managed" and "decorated" are, then a trip to your favorite search engine is a good start.  You *ill* need to know these.